# adding sparkbutton and circleimageview

Tags: android, native-android

**Caused by:**

> `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.`

*Please help me to solve this issue and run app succesfully*

Comment: Can you share more of the error stacktrace please, I think there is more information available

Comment: You may also add a code example.